# Flutter ListView inside Card

Tags: listview, flutter

I would like to have a Screen which will have 3 Cards. 
One card would be CotrolWidget(Top with fixed height), Second will be the MeasurementsList(under Top, should fill vertically) and third will be ChartWidget(under Top, right from the MeasurementsList,should fill vertically).

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: new Text('Measurements')),
  body: new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black12),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(children: [ControlsWidget(device)]),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              MeasurementList(device)
              ,
              ChartWidget(device)
            ],
          )
        ],
      )),
);
```

In the Measurements Card, I would like to have a ListView. But when I use Expaded, the ListView will extend the screen and the list is not scrollable

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: Card(
    elevation: 4.0,
    child: ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(title: Text(measurements[index]));
      },
      itemCount: measurements.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

So, how to create a Card with ListView inside?

Comment: Does GridView work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because there will be 3 Cards with different sizes, based on screen size

Comment: Could you try to change scrollDirection: Axis.horinzontal to Axis.vertical?

Comment: It didn't help. Still the same result

Comment: So, if I understand correct - you set width of second Card according to the screen width. And what about height of second Card - how large it has to be?

Comment: No, I didn't set any width. Width of the MeasurementList(left card) is set by flex:1, ChartWidget(right card) has flex:3, so MeasurementsLIst has 25% of screen width and ChartWidget has 75% of screen width. At the moment the height of MeasurementList(left card) is automatically calcluted from measurements count. But I would like to have height of MeasurementList and ChartWidget to be set to match the parent(entire screen below the ControlsWidget - TopCard)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `MediaQuery` for height.

`MediaQueryData queryData;
queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);`

and then in height use

`height: queryData.size.height - height_of_ControlsWidget`

Comment: Height of what? I don't think this will help, but I will try it.

Comment: you can wrap the card in a container and set the height of the container i believe.

Comment: Try this: `Card(
                child: new SizedBox(
                  height: your_height,
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new Text('First card'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),`

Comment: Yes, setting size will work, but is "hacking". The problem is, I have to set size height: queryData.size.height - someNumber, where someNumber, is not the height of ControlWidget, but some different number and can not be calculated. In my case i have height of ControlWidget 48 and someNumber is 168. I tried to figure it out what this number can be, by sum the padding and appbar height, but it is not 168

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same problem, but I tired to use the **Flexible Widget** instead of expanded widget.

check out this [stack over link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577835/center-expanded-listview-inside-column-flutter) for better understanding.