# Center Expanded ListView inside Column Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to build a layout where there are two Text objects at the top and bottom which stays stationery and a ListView at their center.

Here's the code for the Screen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                child: Text(
                  DateFormat("hh:mm 'PM ,'  MMMM d").format(DateTime.now()),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 4,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      CustomAppText(
                        text: 'Custom App',
                      ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Settings",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output of the given code
[image: Output of given code]

The Design I'm looking for
[image: Desired output]

I have tried using the Center widget but it does not center the ListView

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The ListView fills the entire Expanded Widget, that's why using the Center widget didn't work, so `shrinkWrap: true` should be added so the ListView takes only the height of it's children.

After skimming through the documentation I found about Flexible Widget

```
Flexible, which does not force the child to fill the available space.
```

Made the change and works like a charm

```
Flexible(
  child: ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: 4,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
    CustomAppText(
      text: 'Custom App',
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: That doesn't actually solve the issue. Now ListView isn't expanded, it just takes enough space.

Comment: Perfect answer :)

Comment: Perfect answer...

Answer (score 23):

For those still looking for an answer, this is what worked for me:

```
Column(
  children: [

    Container(), // some top content

    Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [] //your list view content here
        )
      )
    ),

    Container(), // some bottom content

  ]
)
```

The **Expanded** widget makes the content take up all available space.

The **Center** widget centers the content you want to display.

The **ListView** holds your list content and the **"shrinkWrap: true"** property makes your list view shrink according to content size(allowing it to centralized by the **Center** widget when it's not taking a lot of space).

Comment: Thank you for the solution and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helps. Give the top and bottom widgets the 25% of the screen size. Give the listview the 50% of the screen size.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              // Top Widgets
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                // color: Colors.green,
                height: _size.height * 0.25, // Take 25% width of the screen height
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('11: 25 AM', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23.0),),
                    Text('Set As Launcher', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23.0),)
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  // color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: ListView(
                    children: List.generate(25, (index){
                      return Text('Custom App $index', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45.0),);
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              // Bottom Widgets
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                // color: Colors.blue,
                height: _size.height * 0.25, // Take 25% width of the screen height
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Settings', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23.0),),                    
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `Expanded` as a wrapper for your first `Container` inside the `Column`

```
        Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                          child: Text(
                            DateFormat("hh:mm 'PM ,'  MMMM d").format(DateTime.now()),
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: That pushes the entire column down near the settings, and not to the center

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your ListView.builder inside a container class and give it a height, either explicitly in double or as a percentage of screen height.

```
class Trial extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Some Text",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
//                height: 40,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 20,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Text("Hello");
                  }
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Settings",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add two spacer it will give you 100% same result as you expected**

```
      Spacer(),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 4,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  CustomAppText(
                    text: 'Custom App',
                  ),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
```

Answer (score 0):

It have to use shrinkWrap: true and Flexible together to show
all items of ListView.

```
Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: models.length,
```

Answer (score -1):

If you replace your `Expanded` widget with a `Container` and give that a fixed `height`, I think you get what you are looking for.

Comment: That would mean I have to explicitly provide a height which is an hacky solution

Comment: You need the center the widget inside the CustomAppText which will look as if the listview is at the center.