# Flutter ListView crashes inside column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need some help figuring out how I can render the ListView.

I have been following along a Flutter tutorial and I have had to stop because I can't get around this issue.

From what I can understand the ListView tries to take up an infinite amount of space which obviously crashes the app.

I have also come to understand the you can't have a ListView as a direct child of a Column/Row (I explain what I have tried to do about that below)
https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints#flex

Here's the code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ProductControl(_addProduct),
      ),
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _products.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('assets/food.jpg'),
                  Text(_products[index])
                ],
              ),
            ),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

This is what is being said in the beginning of the stacktrace:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
flutter: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
flutter: Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their 
container.In this case, a vertical
flutter: viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in 
which to expand. This situation
flutter: typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside 
another scrollable widget.
flutter: If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there 
is no need to use a viewport because
flutter: there will always be enough vertical space for the children. 
In this case, consider using a Column
flutter: instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property 
(or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
flutter: the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
```

And this is taken from the bottom of the stacktrace:

```
flutter: The following RenderObject was being processed when the 
exception was fired:
flutter:   RenderViewport#cab62 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   creator: Viewport ← _ScrollableScope ← IgnorePointer- 
[GlobalKey#b71f9] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
flutter:   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector- 
[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#d0420] ←
flutter:   _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#02b55] ← Scrollable ← 
PrimaryScrollController ← ListView ← Column ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: <none> (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=375.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
flutter:   size: MISSING
flutter:   axisDirection: down
flutter:   crossAxisDirection: right
flutter:   offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#892dc(offset: 0.0, 
range: null..null, viewport: null,
flutter:   ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> 
BouncingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#9455f,
flutter:   ScrollDirection.idle)
flutter:   anchor: 0.0
flutter: This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to 
depth 5):
flutter:   RenderSliverPadding#c8ab3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:     RenderSliverList#66f1b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
```

I have tried to wrap the ListView.builder in an Expanded widget but that doesn't work for me. (Which is what is being done in the tutorial)

I tried to wrap the Column in an IntrinsicHeight Widget with no success.

The only way I manage to get around this issue is by wrapping the ListView.builder in a Container widget with a set height property. But having to use a Container with a set height does not seem right to me.

I can try to post the full code to recreate this if needed.

Comment: 'shrinkWrap: true' worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53579103/6602400

Answer (score 22):

try using '**Expanded**' instead of Container or other layouts:

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            //color: Colors.white,
            child:
            ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    title: new Text('title'),
                    subtitle: new Text('sub title'),
                    onTap: () => clicked(list[index]['url']),
                    onLongPress: () => downloadAndStoreFile(list[index]['url'],
                        list[index]['name'], list[index]['title']),
                  );
                }),
          )
        ],
),
```

Answer (score 14):

Add this to ListView.Builder =

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ProductControl(_addProduct),
      ),
      ListView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), ///
      shrinkWrap: true, ///
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, ///
        itemCount: _products.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('assets/food.jpg'),
                  Text(_products[index])
                ],
              ),
            ),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: This fixed nothing in my case.

Comment: Thanks @Farick. "shrinkWrap: true," works.

Answer (score 9):

I think I managed to solve this as a last minute effort right after posting the question.

Something I didn't show in my question was another piece of code.

Basically this is what my code looked like.

```
body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: ProductControl(_addProduct),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _products.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('assets/food.jpg'),
                Text(_products[index])
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
   ],
 ),
```

The issue was that I had a Column with a Column as a direct child and apparently ListView does not like that.. So by removing the first Column I could then wrap my ListView in an Expanded widget and everything works. Maybe this can help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Both `Column` and `ListView` expands their size to maximum => Error

**3 Solutions:**

1. Wrap `ListView` with `Expanded` or `Flexible`

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(),
    )
  ],
)
```

2. Limit `ListView` height with `Container` or `SizedBox`

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 200,
      child: ListView(),
    )
  ],
)
```

3. My favorite solution: just add `shrinkWrap` and `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    )
  ],
)
```